# Dynamically add .dll into web application

Tags: asp.net

I need to add assembly into my asp.net application whithout local copy to bin folder, without adding it to GAC. It should be path-reference like C:\bin and this folder is not subfolder of application. Does anybody have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for that:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("path here");
```

With the `assembly` instance, you can execute methods on the fly and pretty much do everything.

Also worth noting that with ASP.NET you run as a different user with less privileges in the operating system, so proper permissions have to be set over the folder where the DLL is located.